# what is the difference between {binding} and {binding Account}?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

here  , i am confuse on  {binding} and {binding Account}.when to use only simple {binding} and binding with proprty name  in below code binding occur as :Content="{Binding}"

```
 <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
         Style="{StaticResource MainBorderStyle}" 
         Background="{StaticResource ResourceListGradientBrush}"
         BorderThickness="0,0,1,1"
         Padding="0">
     <StackPanel>
         <HeaderedContentControl 
             Content="{Binding}"
             ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CommandsTemplate}"/>
     </StackPanel>
 </Border>
```

where is below code binding occur 
as

```
Text="{Binding Path=Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

so i want to know use of them and difference of them.thank in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{Binding}` will simply bind to the actual object set in the `DataContext`. `{Binding Account}` will bind to the Property `Account` on that object.

In your case if you had a `ViewModel` set against the root level `DataContext` then `Account` would be a property called `Account` on the `ViewModel`

Where you have

```
<HeaderedContentControl
            Content="{Binding}"
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CommandsTemplate}"/>
```

All this is doing is setting the `Content` of the `HeaderedContentControl` to the `ViewModel` provided you have something like this in the code behind of the `Window` or `UserControl`

```
 DataContext = yourViewModel;
```

Comment: :is datacontext and itemsource same ?the code for itemsource is here <wpftoolkit:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Account}"

Comment: No. The DataContext is available on any control up the tree. Typically this is set on the Window or root level control/user control if you are using mvvm. Any mvvm examples set this. Then within child controls when you have `{Binding Account}` it will search up the visual tree for the first object set against a DataContext and then bind to a property on that. In this case it will be the Account property

Answer (score 3):

`{Binding}` will bind to the current `DataContext`

`{Binding Account}` will bind to an `Account` property on the current `DataContext`